# Entropy function inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, entropy

Let $$h(p) = -p\log_2(p) - (1-p)\log_2(1-p)$$ be the binary entropy function and $$H(p,q) = -p\log_2(p) -q\log_2(q) - (1-p-q)\log_2(1-p-q)$$ be the "ternary" entropy function. I would like to prove that for all possible values of $p \in [0,1/2]$ and $q \in [0,1/2]$, $$H(p,q) \leq h\bigg(\frac{1-p}{2}\bigg)+h\bigg(\frac{1-q}{2}\bigg).$$
Any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write entropy in the standard form $H(p_1,..,p_n) = - \sum_i p_i\log_2(p_i)$ with $\sum_i p_i = 1$. We can make use of the sub-additivity of entropy (see e.g. [here](http://www.mtm.ufsc.br/~taneja/book/node6.html)) to write

$$
H(a,1-a) + H(b,1-b) \geq H(0,a,b,1-a-b)
$$
Further, $H(0,a,b,1-a-b) = H(a,b,1-a-b)$. Now set $a = (1-p)/2$ and $b = (1-q)/2$. So it suffices to show

$$
D(p,q) = H((1-p)/2, (1-q)/2, 1-(1-p)/2 - (1-q)/2)- H(p,q,1-p-q) \geq 0
$$

Now $D$ has one unique minimum since the two equations $d D / dp = 0$ and $d D / dq = 0$ have only one solution at $p=q=1/3$ with $D(1/3,1/3) = 0$, and since $D>0$ on  the boundaries of the required area $[p=0, p=1/2, q = 0, q = 1/2]$.